# phoneGap iOs PluginManager

Tags: ios, cordova

I use phonegap/cordova >= 3.0.0

Unfortunately I don't have an apple developer-membership.
Therefor I created a brandnew phonegap project on my mac. Without developer-key I couldn't run the project from the termina. So I opened xCode and I imported the created project. Now I put my android-project files from my windows computer into the www-order of the mac.

If I now start the app on a simulator by xCode, I always get a pluginManager message I don't understand:
[image]

Edit:

I added the plugin by console and now I get this error on xCode:
[image]

I just put the entire phonegap folder from android into the ios www folder of xCode. Do I have to readd the plugins on mac then?

Comment: you have to use the iOS' cordova.js, it's different from the android's cordova.js

Comment: project structure is quite different for android and ios. you should use the cli to add ios platform in the project and add the plugins for that platform.

Comment: I listed the plugins .. there was no plugin installed. I added the plugin and now I have an error while I deplay the project. See Editd post